# Translate nouns using SPARQL with Babelnet

Tags: sparql

The following query translates a word to a certain language:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?translation WHERE {
    ?entries a lemon:LexicalEntry .
    ?entries rdfs:label "apple"@en .
    ?entries lemon:sense ?sense .
    ?sense lexinfo:translation ?translation .
    filter contains(str(?translation),"HI")
}
```

But how can I retrieve the label for the translation, which is a LexicalSense as far I can tell

Comment: What would be the label that you expect to see?

Comment: With `?translation ?p ?o.`you can see the only "useful" related nodes are by the `:reference` property, i.e. for apple you get http://babelnet.org/rdf/s00005054n  - but here no label is attached and again, which label do you expect?

Comment: Well Babelnet is multilingual encyclopedic dictionary? So maybe the expectation would be that it's possible to input "apple" and  retrieve  सेब, for example

Comment: Your query should include `PREFIX` statements for `lemon:` ([`<http://lemon-model.net/lemon#>`? `<http://www.monnet-project.eu/lemon#>`? other?](http://prefix.cc/lemon)) and `lexinfo:` ([`<http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#>`?](http://prefix.cc/lexinfo)) and `rdfs:` (`<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>`)... else, it's invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way up and the way down is one and the same (as Heraclitus had said):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?label WHERE {

?original_entry rdfs:label "apple"@en .
    ?original_entry lemon:sense ?original_sense .
        ?original_sense
        lexinfo:translation
        ?translated_sense .
    ?translated_entry lemon:sense ?translated_sense . 
?translated_entry rdfs:label ?label .

FILTER (lang(?label) = "hi") 
}
```

[Try it!](http://babelnet.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbabelnet.org%2Frdf%2F&qtxt=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Flabel+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Foriginal_entry+rdfs%3Alabel+%22apple%22%40en+.%0D%0A++++%3Foriginal_entry+lemon%3Asense+%3Foriginal_sense+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Foriginal_sense%0D%0A+++++++++lexinfo%3Atranslation%0D%0A++++++++%3Ftranslated_sense+.%0D%0A++++%3Ftranslated_entry+lemon%3Asense+%3Ftranslated_sense+.+%0D%0A%3Ftranslated_entry+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0AFILTER+%28lang%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+%22hi%22%29+%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=100000&debug=on)

---

[This page](https://www.w3.org/community/bpmlod/wiki/Converting_BabelNet_as_Linguistic_Linked_Data) describes data model and provides some example queries.